# Is it more Pythonic (and/or performant) to use or to avoid coroutines when making coroutine tail calls in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

In Python 3.5+, I often end up with a situation where I have many nested coroutines just in order to call something that's deeply a coroutine, where the `await` merely comes in a tail call in most of the functions, like this:

```
import asyncio

async def deep(time):
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    return time

async def c(time):
    time *= 2
    return await deep(time)

async def b(time):
    time *= 2
    return await c(time)

async def a(time):
    time *= 2
    return await b(time)

async def test():
    print(await a(0.1))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test())
loop.close()
```

Those functions `a`, `b`, and `c` could be written as regular functions that return a coroutine, instead of as coroutines themselves, as follows:

```
import asyncio

async def deep(time):
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    return time

def c(time):
    time *= 2
    return deep(time)

def b(time):
    time *= 2
    return c(time)

def a(time):
    time *= 2
    return b(time)

async def test():
    print(await a(0.1))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test())
loop.close()
```

Which way is more Pythonic? Which way is more performant? Which way will be easier for others to maintain in the future?

#### Edit — Performance Measurement

As a performance test, I removed the `await asyncio.sleep(time)` line from `deep` and timed 1,000,000 iterations of `await a(0.1)`.  On my test system with CPython 3.5.2, the first version took around 2.4 second and the second version took around 1.6 seconds. So it looks like there may be a performance penalty to making everything coroutines, but it's certainly not an order of magnitude. Perhaps someone with more experience profiling Python code could create a proper benchmark and address the performance issue definitively.

Comment: I like the second one.  For performance you'll need to test it yourself.  In any case this is off topic for SO, as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @JohnZwinck What about this makes it opinion-based? I'd be happy to revise the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use first one: you not only show explicitly places where code can be suspended (where `await` is placed) but also get all related benefits, such as tracebacks that show helpful execution flow.

To see the difference, change your `deep` coroutine to throw some error:

```
async def deep(time):
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    raise ValueError('some error happened')
    return time
```

For first snippet you'll see this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tmp.py", line 116, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
  File ".\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File ".\tmp.py", line 113, in test
    print(await a(0.1))
  File ".\tmp.py", line 110, in a
    return await b(time)
  File ".\tmp.py", line 106, in b
    return await c(time)
  File ".\tmp.py", line 102, in c
    return await deep(time)
  File ".\tmp.py", line 97, in deep
    raise ValueError('some error happened')
ValueError: some error happened
```

But for second snippet only:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tmp.py", line 149, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
  File ".\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File ".\tmp.py", line 146, in test
    print(await a(0.1))
  File ".\tmp.py", line 130, in deep
    raise ValueError('some error happened')
ValueError: some error happened
```

As you can see  first traceback helps you to see "real" (and helpful) flow of execution, while second one not.

First way to write code is also much better to maintain: imagine you once understood that `b(time)` should also contain some async call such as `await asyncio.sleep(time)`. In first snippet this call can be placed directly without any other changes, but in second one you'll have to rewrite many parts of your code.

Comment: What you're saying largely makes sense. One question: You say that `b(time)` should be a coroutine in case it is later modified to perform an async call. Does this logically imply that *all* Python functions should be written as coroutines (with `async`), for that same reason? If not, why not?

Comment: @JohnSpeeks function should be coroutine in two cases: if it already awaits some coroutine inside or if you think it might happen in a future. But if you sure that function won't await something in a future, there's no sense to make it coroutine. I find it rather easy to detect in real life: since we use asynchronous code to get benefit of I/O operations in 99% of cases, question you should ask yourself is "Would this function need to get something from I/O?". If "yes" it'll probably'll need to await something - make it coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases where "is it Pythonic?" is actually *not* an opinion-based question. Tail call optimization is officially un-Pythonic:

> So let me defend my position (which is that I don't want [tail recursion elimination] in the language). If you want a short answer, it's simply unpythonic - [the BDFL](https://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html)

([see also](https://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html))

Comment: The question is not about tail call optimisation, as far as i can tell. In ordinary Python there is none anyway.

Comment: Oh, I did jump over some explanation there, didn't I? Writing `return async_fn()` instead of `return await async_fn()` is equivalent to performing a manual tail-call optimization, because the caller's frame returns before `async_fn` starts executing.

Comment: Indeed, i did not pay attention, sorry. In this case, however, if it is manual, i do not see how it can be "un-Pythonic". It would be IMO like saying that implementing a state machine or a trampoline or an `asyncio` library in Python is un-Pythonic.

Comment: Eh, you can certainly write un-Pythonic code in Python, otherwise we wouldn't need the word un-Pythonic. And it's funny you say that, because I'm kind of notorious for arguing that `asyncio` is un-Pythonic in many ways :-) see e.g. [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLkfnc_UMcE), [2](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Ah, that's you, i didn't recognize your name. What is funny is that i've stumbled upon your blog post on comparison on `asyncio` and `curio`, and on your `trio` library just about last week. Still looking into it. As to my remark, i intended to say that any async library, any state machine implementation, etc., could be declared "un-Pythonic" by a similar argument, since there is some cheating to make goto-ish "calls" without using up call stack. Probably i was wrong about "any async library," `trio` looks disciplined enough to avoid goto-ish "calls." Still, i find you argument far-fetched...

Comment: Anyway, even in `trio` you can juggle nurseries (and it is considered ok), so it is not clear to me why juggling callbacks or continuations would be less "Pythonic." Instead of returning a function to be called by a trampoline, you can schedule that function on the running event loop and return normally. I do not see why the rejection of TCO by the BDFL makes one of these tricks "un-Pythonic," but not the other.